# SwiftUI preview issue while using environment locale

Tags: localization, swiftui, nsnumberformatter

I am using a simple view to display text in `NumberFormatter` for a specific locale

```
struct CurrencyView: View {
    let currency:Currency
    var body: some View {
        Text(currency.getFormattedCurrency())
    }
}

struct CurrencyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CurrencyView(currency: Currency(currencyValue: 1.0)).previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300.0, height: 55.0)).environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "fr_Fr"))
    }
}

struct Currency{
    let currencyValue:Double

    func getFormattedCurrency() -> String{
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        let formatterCurrency =  formatter.string(for: self.currencyValue) ?? ""
        return formatterCurrency
    }
}
```

I was expecting the preview will show currency in `French` with € as I have already mentioned in Locale in preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4

[image: demo]

```
struct CurrencyView: View {
    @Environment(\.locale) var locale
    let currency:Currency
    var body: some View {
        Text(currency.getFormattedCurrency(for: locale))
    }
}

struct CurrencyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CurrencyView(currency: Currency(currencyValue: 1.0))
            .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "fr_Fr"))
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300.0, height: 55.0))
    }
}

struct Currency{
    let currencyValue:Double

    func getFormattedCurrency(for locale: Locale) -> String{
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = locale
        let formatterCurrency =  formatter.string(for: self.currencyValue) ?? ""
        return formatterCurrency
    }
}
```

Comment: So does it mean, we will have to pass the Locale Object without which Swift UI Preview would not show in the locale format which are expecting?